# display array in a function - not working

Tags: bash, debian, array, function

What am I missing here?

I have created a simple array:

```
declare -a appArray=(
    "item1 -a -b"
    "item2 -c -d"
    )
```

If I echo this I can see it all

```
echo ${appArray[@]}

> item1 -a -b item2 -c -d
```

I then create a function as follows:

```
fc_DEBUG () { 
    if [ $1 -eq 1 ] ; then 
        echo $2; 
    fi; 
};
```

It is designed to sit in a bash script, and if I set a DEBUG variable it will echo the text back. So I can use it throughout the script without needing to manually add / remove things.

It works fine with basic data:
e.g

```
fc_DEBUG $DEBUG "This is DEBUG text"
```

If I call this with the Array however, I only get a part of the Array.

```
fc_DEBUG $DEBUG "${appArray[@]}"

> item1 -a -b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`${appArray[@]}` gets expanded before `fc_DEBUG` runs. So the second argument the function sees, is the first of the array. To be explicit, the three arguments `fc_DEBUG` sees, are

```
$DEBUG "item1 -a -b" "item2 -c -d"
```

(replace $DEBUG with the words resulting from the split+glob operator applied to the actual value of $DEBUG (as you forgot to quote it)). In technical terms, the array is passed by value, not by reference.

```
fc_DEBUG () { 
    if [ "$1" -eq 1 ] ; then 
        shift
        echo "$@"
    fi
}
```

Now, the first argument is dropped from the argument list with `shift`, and the rest of all the arguments is printed.

Call it with a quoted array:

```
fc_DEBUG "$DEBUG" "${appArray[@]}"
```

Comment: That's great cheers. Good explanation too.